# SEGMENTATION FAULT in C++ - Rougewave (only in linux and not in unix)

Tags: c++, memory, gdb, segmentation-fault, rogue-wave

Hi I am facing memory fault with my code. I used gdb and found out where memory fault occurs. But I am not able to solve that. The lines of code where memory fault occurs is below. Please help me friends.

```
void CJob::print_parm_file(){
int m_nFuncid;
CCmdset*  pCmdset = NULL;
const int size=1024;
char      fname[80];
char      dbg_buf[size]="";
unsigned int i, gotit=0;

for (i=0; i < entries(); i++)
{
pCmdset  = (CCmdset*)  at(i);

//RWCollectableString *cmdset = (RWCollectableString *)pCmdset->at(0);
//RWCString m_Function=cmdset->data();

CXmlobj *xobj = (CXmlobj *)pCmdset->at(0);

cout <<"The value of m_name.data() //segfault issue is : " << xobj->m_name << endl;
cout <<"The value of m_name.data() //segfault issue is : " << xobj->m_name.data() << endl;
RWCString m_Function=xobj->m_name.data();  //segmentation fault occurs in this line
```

I have printed the value of m_name.data() to check its value. when i tried printing its value, segmentation fault occured in cout statements itself.

NOTE : This issue is happening only in Linux server. The code is working perfect in Unix server without any issue.

Please help me ! Thanks !!!

Comment: Just a note, C style casts like `(CCmdset*)` are **strongly** discouraged in C++. You should seriously consider using C++ casting operators like `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Oh.. I did not know it. Also, this piece of code works perfectly in Unix. The segmentation fault occurs only in Linux server

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that `m_name` is of type `std::string`. There is no guarantee that a null character terminates the character sequence pointed by the value returned by `data()`. Simply put, your prints may access more elements than that string actually contains which causes this segmentation fault.

Try adding a `\0` character at the end of the string, or replace `data()` with `c_str()` which is guaranteed to be null-terminated.

Comment: I used strcpy command instead of assigning value to m_Function. But the issue is m_nme.data has no value it seems.

Comment: oh. Does the fault take place when you prints `m_name.data()`? What's the type of `m_name`?

Comment: yes.. when i print m_name.data(), no vzlue is printed for m_name.data() and it displays : 
    The value of m_name.data() //segfault issue is : memory fault. The type of m_name is : RWCString m_name;

Comment: That's the problem. You can't print the return value of std::string::data() directly as it's NOT null-terminated. Try adding a `\0` character at the end of the string and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Ok.. I ll assign a value with null termination to ""RWCString m_Function" and check.

Comment: You don't have to manually assign the null terminator. Just call `c_str()` instead of `data()`.

Comment: Do NOT put null termination in manually, you will screw compatibility between s.size() and strlen().

Comment: @n.m. It won't. `s.size()` is guaranteed to be the same with `s.length()`, isn't it?

Comment: @EricZ s.length() is not strlen(s.c_str()).

Comment: @n.m. Again, they both stops at the first occurrence of `\0`.

Comment: @Captain .. The reason for assigning a value myself is that m_name.data() is not having any value in  it !

Comment: @n.m. ok. That's not suprising.

Comment: I m getting the following error while making the exe : \../Job.cpp: In member function 'void CJob::print_rpt_file()':
../Job.cpp:212: error: 'class RWCString' has no member named 'c_str'
make: *** [Job.o] Error 1

Comment: @Toshi, that's why I'm asking if `m_name` is of type `std::string` at the beginning. Does adding a `\0` at the end of your string work?

Comment: @Eric .. memory fault is happening at the same place :(

Comment: Sorry.. memory fault now occurs in the line "delete job" in the Main function. But the function "print_rpt_file" is not giving out the report files which we ususally get

Comment: @Toshi, This conversation is way too long to be effective. Try debug the code yourself. If there's still a problem, repost it with more precise information given.

Answer (score 0):

Did you first establish that xobj is valid?

```
CXmlobj *xobj = (CXmlobj *)pCmdset->at(0);  // if xobj is invalid
xobj->m_name.data();   // ... then this will invoke undefined behavior
```

The simplest thing to try is just assign that string variable to a temporary string variable and see what happens.  If you still get a segmentation fault, then the problem is more than likely that xobj is not pointing to a valid CXmlobj.

Comment: Yes thats a valid one ! .. Does the same code behave differently in linux and unix ?

Comment: I updated my post.  Please make sure it really is valid by assigning that string to a temporary string.

Comment: According to this link:
[link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-3702/CSt_8054.htm)

RWCString is a copy-on-write string.  So take that string and assign it to a temporary string.  If it still seg faults, then either xobj is invalid, or you've totally hosed the COW string handling mechanism in some way.